# Missing parameter(s): email, password error is occurring on posting data in angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-compiler-cli

I am new to angular 4. I am working on login page in which I have to post the user information on login.But I am getting error as 
"code":"rest_missing_callback_param","message":"Missing parameter(s): email, password" on posting data.Below is my code:

```js
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response,Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private http:Http,private router:Router) { }
login(){
this.router.navigate(['login']);
}
     createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa('ck_543700d9f8c08268d75d3efefb302df4fad70a8f:cs_f1514261bbe154d662eb5053880d40518367c901')); 
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  }   
onSubmit(userForm:NgForm){
    console.log(userForm.value);
    let headers=new Headers();
     this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
const body={
 "email": userForm.value.email,
  "first_name": userForm.value.fname,
  "last_name": userForm.value.lname,
  "username": userForm.value.uname,
  "password": userForm.value.password
}
    console.log(body);
    console.log(headers);
this.http.post('https://www.colourssoftware.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v2/customers',body,{
        headers:headers
        })
      .subscribe(
      data => {
              console.log(data);
            },
            err => {
              console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
            }
      );

}   
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
 <form class="animated wow slideInUp" data-wow-delay=".5s" #regForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(regForm)">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name..." required=" " name="fname" ngModel>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name..." required=" " name="lname" ngModel>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="UserName..." required=" " name="uname" ngModel>
                    <h6 class="animated wow slideInUp" data-wow-delay=".5s">Login information</h6>

                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required=" " name="email" ngModel>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required=" " name="password" ngModel>
                    <div class="register-check-box">
                        <div class="check">
                            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><i> </i>I accept the terms and conditions</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Register">
                </form>
```

Where I have done the mistake? How can I post the data to the server in angular 4? Please help me.

Comment: please at first read: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: Eventhough Iam getting data from html,but email and password are not passed into the server

Comment: ok, are You handle the email and password in client side???

Comment: Actually Iam using wordpress APIs.So for authorisation I had used headers.so I don't anything about client side

Comment: Your code above is in `angular`, `angular` is client-side framework...

Comment: ok.Iam getting all the data that is mentioned in the body variable that passing into the post method but it doesnot taking email and password,remaining data was going

Comment: Your problem it's easy to solve, but Your code is so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within you submit method you are forming a JSON object, but you send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. My guess is that you should set you headers to `application/json` instead.

Comment: Its not helping, my request has headers set properly still i get same above error.

Comment: When you inspect the request, is payload set correctly, too?

Comment: yes, it is but actually, I have already found the solution. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old question but I'm answering this so that other people might benefit.

```
> You should use yoursite.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v2/users API instead
> of yoursite.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v2/customers
```

when validating user login or registering customers with WordPress rest API.
also, make sure that you have valid authorization set in header.

*** If you want to use yoursite.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v2/customers API then you must have that customer account with that same username/password in WordPress then only you will be able to validate as a customer with woocommerce api